# Is there a better way to refactor map and filter code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have an array of data. array contains over 500k items. I want to map items in the array then fileter it. This is what I have done.

I create a function that filters array tpo get unique values

```
const getUniqueValues = (array: string[]): string[] => {
  return array.filter((item, index, _array) => _array.indexOf(item) === index);
};
```

then I pass in the mapped data into the function

```
const uniqueValues = getUniqueValues(
  editedData.map((bodyItem: any) => bodyItem[index])
).filter(Boolean);
```

This worked well and faster when the array contains less items. Now, it takes sometimes five to ten minutes to perform action, which isn't good for user experience. Now `uniqueValue` returns aproximately `210,000 items` in array

Is there a better way to perform this in less time?

I have tried `array.reduce`, not sure of my code tho cos it seems not to solve the problem. if someone could check it out, i'll appreciate

```
          const uniqueValues = editedData.reduce(
            (accumulator, bodyItem) => {
              const item = bodyItem[index];
              if (!accumulator.includes(item)) {
                accumulator.push(item);
              }
              return accumulator;
            },
            []
          );
```

Comment: can you include `editedData` and `index`?

Comment: Also don't just read the first snippet of the first answer in a duplicate. The above flagged dupe has 150 detailed answers with benchmarks for a lot of the different options.

Answer (score 1):

With that high amount of items, you should be using the builtin [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) class, which will get rid of duplicates efficiently. Just replace `getUniqueValues` with the code below

```
const getUniqueValues = (array: string[]): string[] => {
  return [...new Set(array)];
};
```

Comment: vote to close as [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33121880/13762301)

Answer (score -1):

can you try this :

```
const uniqueValues = Array.from(new Set(editedData.map((bodyItem: any) => bodyItem[index]))).filter(Boolean);
```

- new Set(editedData.map((bodyItem: any) => bodyItem[index])) creates a Set, automatically removing any duplicate values.
- Array.from() then converts this Set back into an array.
- .filter(Boolean) filters out any falsy values.